# Why are pointers not convertible to references?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I've read in multiple sources that a C++ reference is no more than a pointer with compile time restrictions.

If this is true, how come I am forced to dereference a pointer in order to pass it to a function that expects a parameter?

```
void FooRef(const int&);
void FooPointer(const int*);

int main()
{
    int* p = new int(5);
    FooPointer(p);
    FooRef(*p); // why do I have to dereference the pointer?

    ...
}
```

As I understand it, if I were to pass an `int` to `FooRef` the compiler would create the pointer (reference) from the address of the variable for me, but if the type is already a pointer then dereferencing it seems pointless. It seems to me like I am dereferencing a pointer, just to let the compiler create another pointer from the dereferenced value which seems senseless to me.
Wouldn't it be simpler / more performant to just copy the pointer instead of just referencing+derferencing the value? (Perhaps this is really what's happening?)

Am I missing something here? and does calling `FooRef` in such a scenario be slower than calling `FooPointer`?
And do references and pointers really produce the same code during compilation?

Comment: A reference is IMO much more an alias - another name for an object. It might be implemented by a pointer sometimes (it's not always necessary, the compiler might substitute it for the original name in some cases).

Comment: the dereference operation here is nothing more than syntactic sugar.  You have to *write* a dereference, but none actually is performed.

Comment: Note you can call `FooRef(5);` but not `FooPointer(&5);`.

Comment: Another example: `int a = 42; int& b = a; b = 33;` might as well be optimized to `int a = 42; a = 33;`

Comment: @HalCanary Are you sure? Because judging by the answers so far people seem reluctant to make such claims...

Comment: If you like, you can think of a function parameter being a reference as adding an implicit `&` to the parameter when it is called, so that code looks like `FooRef(&(*p))`. Now it's pretty clear that `FooRef(&(p))` won't work, because that will produce an `int**` not an `int*` (`int*` behaves the same as an `int&` after compilation. The difference is syntax and where you can use them)

Comment: All I am saying is that when you compile those functions down to machine language, you won't be able to tell the difference between a reference and a pointer.

Comment: @HalCanary does the language guarantee that it will be so?

Comment: @Acidic: No, the language does not guarantee that. As far as the language specification is concerned, the compiler writers could decide to put a 10 minute sleep in your code whenever you dereference a pointer, and that would be a valid decision.  You just have to trust that the compiler authors are not idiots, or check the code output yourself.

Comment: "does the language guarantee that it will be so? " -- The language guarantees that it's *possible* ... and since it's possible, an optimizing compiler will generate the same code in both cases. What actually *isn't* possible is what you fear ... that you're doing work dereferencing the pointer and then the compiler does more work on top of that to get the address of the result; that isn't possible because that wouldn't result in a reference to the right `int`.

Answer (score 9):

The fact that references can be *implemented* in terms of pointers under the hood is irrelevant.  Many programming concepts can be implemented in terms of other things.  You may as well ask why we have `while` loops when `while` can be implemented in terms of `goto` or `jmp`.  The point of different language concepts is to make things *easier* for the programmer, and references are a language-concept designed for the convenience of the programmer.

You probably are misunderstanding the *purpose* of references.  References give you the positive side of pointers (cheap to pass around), but since they have the same semantics as regular values, they remove a lot of the dangers that come with using pointers: (pointer arithmetic, dangling pointers, etc.)  More importantly, a reference is a totally different *type* than a pointer in the C++ type-system, and it would be madness to allow the two to be interchangeable (that would defeat the purpose of references.)

Reference syntax is designed *on purpose* to mirror the syntax of regular value semantics - while at the same time providing you with the ability to cheaply pass around memory addresses instead of copying entire values.

Now, turning to your example:

```
FooRef(*p); // why do I have to dereference the pointer?
```

You have to dereference the pointer here because `FooRef` takes a *reference* to an `int`, not a reference to an `int*`. Note that you can also have a *reference to a pointer*:

```
void FooPointerRef(const int*&);
```

A function that takes a reference to a pointer enables you to modify the memory address of the pointer from within the function.  In your example, you have to explicitly dereference the pointer to mirror value semantics.  Otherwise, someone looking at the function call `FooRef(p)` is going to think that `FooRef` either takes a pointer-by-value or a pointer-by-reference - but NOT a (non-pointer) value or a reference.

Comment: My question wasn't about the syntax, but about why I am seemingly dereferencing a value just to have the compiler reference it in the same line.

Comment: But I don't. I want to pass a pointer by value (if a reference really is a pointer) instead of having to dereference it just so that the compiler can create a pointer from the dereferenced value.

Comment: @Acidic `void FooRef(const int&);` is designed/intended to have the same calling syntax as `void FooRef(int);` There's basically no difference for an `int` (concerning performance), but a big difference for objects of class type.

Comment: @DyP you don't need to teach me the basics or explain to me the purpose of references...

Comment: by dereferencing it, you tell the compiler that you actually know what you are doing. That you did not pass an X* when you actaully wanted to pass an X. the pass-pointer-by-value implicitly happen anyway, but only as an implementation detail.

Comment: @Acidic Sry it's a bit hard for me to understand what you're asking. But it's clear you need to derefence it for a `void FooCopy(const int);` (w/o reference), and as the syntax is intended to be the same for references as for non-reference types, you have to write the `*` in the call `FooCopy(*p)` as well as `FooRef(*p)`.

Answer (score 2):

The actual argument for a parameter passed by reference is consistently the same type as the parameter, whether it is obtained by dereferencing a pointer or not, and regardless how passing-by-reference is implemented.

Comment: Your second comment would be the start of a good answer. For the first comment, I did not mean to imply multiple implementations -- only that the consistency of the language in this case was more valuable than worrying about the implementation by the compiler.

Comment: I don't know what comments those are, because some sociopath has gone through and deleted those and several other of my (and other people's) comments.

Comment: Disturbing. You had noted that passing-by-reference could only be implemented by passing the address, and corrected the OP's assumption that work was required at runtime when a dereferenced pointer was passed to a reference parameter.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read in multiple sources that a C++ reference is no more than a
>   pointer with compile time restrictions.

Don't believe everything you read.

Comment: Its a dangerous assumption.

Comment: @Acidic It's not an assumption, it's a falsehood ... or a misunderstanding of what you read. *Conceptually*, references and pointers are quite different things. The fact that, in most implementations, the code generated for calling foo(int*) and foo(int&) both pass an address is another matter.

Comment: @JimBalter again, my question was never about the conceptual differences. My question was about the possible performance difference between the two.

Comment: @Acidic You stated that "a C++ reference is no more than a pointer" -- again, that's false and conceptually confused. You deeply misunderstand the language, the concepts, and the nature of compilers. Compiler writers try to generate as efficient code as the language specification allows. That's the answer to your question.

Comment: @Acidic - whenever you see "nothing more than" your bullshit flag should go up. Yes, references are typically **implemented** as pointers, but that has nothing to do with how you write code that uses them. To understand the difference between pointers and references you have to study how references are defined and used, and how pointers are defined and used. They are fundamentally different, and this assertion of equivalence is, at best, misleading.

Comment: @Acidic - actually, what I should have said is that references are typically implemented as addresses, and that pointers are also typically implemented as addresses. There are no pointers in the generated code, just memory addresses.

Comment: @PeteBecker my question wasn't about their uses, but about the implications their use can have on performance.

Answer (score 1):

Pointers in C++ are distinct data types. If C++ would have *coerced* an X* pointer to an X& reference, then how should the following code behave?

```
int x=5;
void* px = (void*)&x;
void*& prx = px;
```

Besides, things will be very weird - since what you want is silence dereference, passing NULL will result in segmentation in the caller code, but the caller will have no syntactic way to see it.

And what will you get in return to this confusion? Some more confusion between implementation details and language abstractions. nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are plenty of answers here, just see for yourself:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void) 
{
    int p = 5;
    int *p_ptr = &p;
    int &p_ref = p;


    printf("Address of p     = %x\n", &p);
    printf("Address of p_ref = %x\n", &p_ref);
    printf("Value   of p_ptr = %x\n", p_ptr);
    printf("Address of p_ptr = %x\n", &p_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Address of p     = 16fd80
Address of p_ref = 16fd80
Value   of p_ptr = 16fd80
Address of p_ptr = 16fd88
```

So, as far as references are concerned--a reference has the same address as the object being referenced. A pointer's *value* is the address of the object being pointed to (or referenced), while still having its own separate address.

Of course, what is produced: (`cl /FA reftest.cpp`)

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
p$ = 32                         ; all our variables
p_ptr$ = 40
p_ref$ = 48
main    PROC
; ... snip ...
mov DWORD PTR p$[rsp], 5        ; p = 5

lea rax, QWORD PTR p$[rsp]      ; p_ptr = &p
mov QWORD PTR p_ptr$[rsp], rax

lea rax, QWORD PTR p$[rsp]      ; p_ref = p
mov QWORD PTR p_ref$[rsp], rax
```

Looks the same to me. 
However consider this: (`cl /O2 /FA reftest.cpp`)

```
_TEXT   SEGMENT
p$ = 48
p_ptr$ = 56
main    PROC     ; notice p_ref is gone
; ... snip ...
```

The best part about references is that they are easy to optimize out of code. A reference can only ever refer to one object during its lifetime, a pointer could reference many different objects during its lifetime, and the compiler must be wary of that fact.

(Note: This is obviously just the assembly resulting from Microsoft's compiler, while the results may vary from compiler to compiler, I suspect most compiler's can pull this one off)

Comment: "So maybe references could be hypothetically an extra instruction or two" -- No, absolutely not. A reference to a value must reference *that* value ... the extra work the OP fears *cannot* be done, else it would be a reference to a copy.

Comment: I'm going to edit that out, you are absolutely right. The more I think about it, the more I realize just how ridiculous it sounds. Following the memory address, to get the value's memory address... IIRC (my assembly's rusty), getting the address of an object doesn't make sense in the first place, because the only way to access the object is with its memory address.

Comment: Note that, even in C, `int* q; int* p = &*q;` doesn't do any extra work ... *it can't*. It's semantically identical to `p = q;`

Answer (score 1):

It would certainly create some interesting confusing cases:

```
int a(int& x)   {    return x + 1;    }
int b(int& x)   {    return x + 2;    }

// now for the fun part, 'b' has another valid overload
int b(int* x)   {    return *x + 3;   }


int  myInt = 1;
int* p = &myInt; // get a pointer to myInt

cout << a(p);    // calls int a(int&) by your rule.  Syntax error in real C++
cout << b(p);    // calls int b(int*), by your rule and real C++.
                 // Isn't that confusing?

cout << a(*p);   // valid, always calls int a(int&)
cout << b(*p);   // valid.  Always calls b(int&)
                 // This isn't confusing, in real C++ or with your rule
```

It would be confusing if you had to constantly remember whether or not to dereference.

The other reason for it is that it simplifies the specification.  The compiler is allowed to assume that a reference ALWAYS refers to a valid object.  It gets to make optimizations based on that assumption.  The way it keeps that guarantee is by making it illegal to deference the null pointer.  If you didn't have to dereference p in the example above, then it couldn't get those guarantees.

References and Pointers have very similar behavior except for the following:

- Pointers can point to null, while references cannot refer to null
- References can refer to values which do not have addresses (such as values stored in registers).  Pointers must always be stored in memory, which can be slower.

Could they have written C++ where you can automatically convert from pointer to reference?  Sure.  There is no real technical reason why they couldn't have.  But the authors of the language decided that it provided more problems than solutions.

There is an old adage, "A language is not complete when you've put everything you can think of into it.  A language is complete when you've taken everything out that you possibly can."   Many will argue C++ has too much baggage to have held true to this adage, but it still tries whenever it can.